# Using Multiple Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Well i am creating a program in which i need a separate window to show the log.

I managed to show another form using

```
form1.ShowDialog();
```

But unfortunately this transfers the focus to the shown form and the user is not able to click on the previous form until he\she closes it.

Question : How could i use 2 separate forms at the same time ( one for the main ui, and one for the logger ).

Comment: `.Show()` instead of `.ShowDialog()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use `form1.Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()`.

The `ShowDialog` method is intended to show the form as a [modal dialog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window), which (by design) will block the original form until `form1` has been closed.

The `Show` method, on the other hand, just opens the new form as a normal Window.

Comment: Well you made my day :D. The fastest good answer i ever got, thanks very much bro.

Comment: Marked! :D, it was the system that told me i can't mark it before 10 minutes